# Adding software.amazon.msk:aws-msk-iam-auth dependency causing software.amazon.awssdk:ssm get parameters by path fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-ssm, aws-msk

My Java application is using the dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/ssm/2.20.149

and i have a role and one policy already added my application is working fine able to get parameters by path .
I am adding one dependency for kafka integration https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.msk/aws-msk-iam-auth/1.1.9

suddenly my application failed to access the ssm parameters getting the error

```
    software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.SsmException: User: arn:aws:sts::****:assumed-role/******/aws-sdk-java-********is not 
authorized to perform: ssm:GetParametersByPath on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:********:parameter/test/abc/ because no identity-based policy allows the 
ssm:GetParametersByPath action (Service: Ssm, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ******)
```

****i don't have any other policy or msk is not yet integrated i just add the dependency alone.**
when i remove the dependency it works fine.**

is there any conflict exist between this dependency
what will be the possible reason?